# Key Filter Constructor Usage Autofac Issue

Tags: autofac, keyfilter

I am trying to achieve Resolving instances using Autofac KeyFilter. I am getting results if explicitly resolve the instances using ResolveKeyed<> . However when using KeyFilter in Constructor i am seeing different instances being resolved as parameters.

here is the small example .. i came up..

```
public enum TestApiEnum
{
    TestA,
    TestB
}
public interface ITestService
{   
}
public interface ITestApi
{
}
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public TestService([KeyFilter(TestApiEnum.TestA)]ITestApi testApiA, 
    [KeyFilter(TestApiEnum.TestB)] ITestApi testApiB)
    {       
    }
}
public class TestApiA : ITestApi
{
    public TestApiA(TestApiEnum testEnum)
    {
        TestApiEnum = testEnum;
    }
    public TestApiEnum TestApiEnum { get; set; }  
}

public class TestApiB: ITestApi
{
    public TestApiB(TestApiEnum testEnum)
    {
        TestApiEnum = testEnum;
    }
    public TestApiEnum TestApiEnum { get; set; }
}
```

---

Builder Registration

```
       builder.RegisterType<TestService>()
            .As<ITestService>();

        builder.RegisterType<TestApiA>()
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .Keyed<ITestApi>(TestApiEnum.TestA)
                .WithAttributeFiltering()
                .WithParameter("testEnum", TestApiEnum.TestA);

        builder.RegisterType<TestApiB>()
               .AsImplementedInterfaces()
               .Keyed<ITestApi>(TestApiEnum.TestB)
               .WithAttributeFiltering()
               .WithParameter("testEnum", TestApiEnum.TestB);
```

---

```
var builder = AutofacConfig.ConfigureContainer();
        using (var scope = builder.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            // Able to Resolve following two..
            var testApiA = scope.ResolveKeyed<ITestApi>(TestApiEnum.TestA);
            var testApiB = scope.ResolveKeyed<ITestApi>(TestApiEnum.TestB);

            // following test service resolves both parameters as **testApiB** and **testApiB**
            var testservice = scope.Resolve<ITestService>();
        }
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have similar problems with KeyFilter ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917583/using-keyfilter-with-asp-net-core-2-0))

In your case it is about the following:
in constructor KeyFilter don't work - it is an issue :-(
it will be resolved **only** by interface, by last registered interface :-(
(in your case TestB)

Check it out.

first case : add:

```
builder.RegisterType<TestApiB>()                   
               .As<ITestApi>()
               .WithAttributeFiltering()
               .WithParameter("testEnum", TestApiEnum.TestC);
```

and comment out your registrations (It doesn't matter) --> you (always) get TestC

Second case: swap initial registration --> last registration will be used.

Third case: comment out lines ".AsImplementedInterfaces()": you will get exception until don't register code of first case.

Answer (score 7):

@A_G answer is not completely true: I was able to make constructor injection work in a .NET Core project with Autofac.

The OP's mistake is the same I made at first: `WithAttributeFiltering()` must be declared at the **consumer** registration, and not when registering the keyed component.

In other words, this is wrong:

```
builder.RegisterType<TestService>()
    .As<ITestService>();

builder.RegisterType<TestApiA>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .Keyed<ITestApi>(TestApiEnum.TestA)
    .WithAttributeFiltering() // << This won't work.
    .WithParameter("testEnum", TestApiEnum.TestA);

builder.RegisterType<TestApiB>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .Keyed<ITestApi>(TestApiEnum.TestB)
    .WithAttributeFiltering() // << Won't also work.
    .WithParameter("testEnum", TestApiEnum.TestB);
```

But this is right:

```
builder.RegisterType<TestService>()
    .As<ITestService>()
    .WithAttributeFiltering(); // << Just a single call here.

builder.RegisterType<TestApiA>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .Keyed<ITestApi>(TestApiEnum.TestA)
    .WithParameter("testEnum", TestApiEnum.TestA);

builder.RegisterType<TestApiB>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .Keyed<ITestApi>(TestApiEnum.TestB)
    .WithParameter("testEnum", TestApiEnum.TestB);
```

I agree it can be confusing, but [Autofac's documentation](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html#keyfilterattribute) is also correct (they could maybe make it even more explicit though, it's easy to get it wrong).