# Using KeyFilter with ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, autofac

I have problem to using KeyFilter attribute in a simple ASP.NET Core 2.0 WebAPI application.

```
<PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="4.6.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="4.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
```

Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac())
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
               .Build();
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public IContainer ApplicationContainer { get; private set; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. 
// Use this method to add services to the container.
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    // Autofac
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.Populate(services);
    builder.RegisterType<ClassX1>()
           .Keyed<IInterfaceX>("first")
           .WithParameter("name", "X1")
           .SingleInstance();

    builder.RegisterType<ClassX1>()
           .Keyed<IInterfaceX>("second")
           .WithParameter("name", "X2")
           .SingleInstance();

    builder.RegisterType<ClassX1>()
           .As<IInterfaceX>()
           .WithParameter("name", "X3")
           .SingleInstance();

    builder.RegisterType<ValuesController>()
           .WithAttributeFiltering();

    ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();

    return ApplicationContainer.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
    // return new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer);
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. 
// Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

ClassX1.cs:

```
public class ClassX1: IInterfaceX
{
    public ClassX1(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
}
```

IInterfaceX.cs:

```
public interface IInterfaceX
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

ValuesController.cs:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IInterfaceX _x;

    public ValuesController([KeyFilter("second")] IInterfaceX x)
    {
        _x = x;
    }

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2", _x.Name };
    }
}
```

Calling "/api/values" yield ["value1","value2","X3"].
But i expect ["value1","value2","X2"].

if i remove the third registration (with X3) then

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'WebApplicationAutofac.IInterfaceX' while attempting to activate 'WebApplicationAutofac.Controllers.ValuesController'.

Trying to direct resolving works correct:

```
var temp = ApplicationContainer.ResolveKeyed<IInterfaceX>("second");
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Why did you comment the return `new AutofacServiceProvider` line ?

Comment: 'return ApplicationContainer.Resolve<IServiceProvider>()'
has the same effect as
'new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer)'
i think the first case is better due to resolution by container.

Comment: It looks like the application doesn't use `Autofac` and uses the built-in DI resolver but can't see why yet

Comment: i have found http://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2017/05/08/add-custom-ioc-in-aspnetcore.html:
services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();

Comment: it works ? if so, post your answer to let everybody know

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works pretty cool for WebAPI Controllers.

The solution is to add .AddControllersAsServices():

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
```

Comment: This method does not exist for .NET 6